# First homology group of $\mathbb{RP}^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I know there are other questions about the computation of $H_1(\mathbb{RP}^2)$ (over a generic coefficient ring) but they all use cellular/simplicial homology methods, while my only "weapon" is Mayer-Vietoris sequence (and of course homotopic invariance of homology).

I already know the homology groups of the spheres.

I managed to compute all of the other homologies but the first one is giving me problems. Basically I saw $\mathbb{RP}^2$ as
$$\mathbb{RP}^2=\frac{D^2}\sim$$
where $D^2$ is a closed disk and $\sim$ identifies antipodal points of $\partial D^2$. Then we can cover the real projective plane as follows:

$$\mathbb{RP}^2=U\cup V$$
$$U=\mathbb{RP}^2-\{0\}$$
$$V=\{x\in D^2: \|x\|<1/2\}$$

Clearly:

$$U\sim S^1/\sim =\mathbb{RP^1}\cong S^1$$
$$U\cap V \sim S^1$$

So the Mayer-Vietoris sequence

$$\cdots\to H_1(U\cap V) \to H_1(U)\oplus H_1(V)\to H_1(\mathbb{RP}^2) \to H_0(U\cap V)\to H_0(U)\oplus H_0(V) \to \cdots$$

becomes:

$$\cdots\to H_1(S^1) \to H_1(S^1)\to H_1(\mathbb{RP}^2) \to H_0(S^1)\to H_0(S^1)\oplus H_0(V) \to \cdots$$

I know that the first map is essentially multiplication by $2$ (it can be seen by working through the identifications). So if the second map was surjective I would be done, but $H_0(S^1)$ is not $0$, so I can't deduce this from the exactness of the sequence. Could you help me?

Comment: It is not too hard to show that the map $H_0(S^1)\to H_0(S^1)\oplus H_0(V)$ is injective, which is all you need to conclude that the preceding map in the exact sequence is surjective.

Comment: You can surely compute the map $H_0(U\cap V)\to H_0(U)$!

Comment: Now I feel stupid :), thank you: this solved my problem.